# Конвертирование строки в число

Tags: php

Как проверить входящую строку число это или нет.

То есть смотрите есть строка

```
$str = 'текст, не число';
```

И нужно проверить если там число, то тогда записать его в переменную, если нет -
 то выполнить другой код. Вот приблизительный алгоритм

```
if (/*логика проверки число это или нет*/)
{
   $count = $str /*логика конверктирования*/;
   #код...
}
else
   echo 'Вы ввели не число!';
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в слове "конвер_к_тирование". И скорее всего вы имеете в виду [приведение типов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `is_int($str)`, если в переменной число, то она вернет **TRUE**, а если нет, то **FALSE**

```
23 - true
'23' - false
23.5 - false
NULL - false
```

**UPD:** Число еще может быть в виде строки (допустим '25') или не целым, тогда эта функция отметит его как  **FALSE**. В таком случае лучше использовать `is_numeric`. Она оценивает строку на наличиее числа в ней.

```
'42' - число
'1337' - число
'not numeric' - НЕ число
'Array' - НЕ число
'9.1' - число
```

Comment: @pavel1787mego, добавил обновление в ответ

Comment: А как насчет `¼` или `፲`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, специальные символы довольно редки, поэтому если нужно, то можно сделать отдельную проверку. А 0.25 которое и есть 1/4 функция принимает.

Answer (score 0):

Хммм, канешн интересный вопрос, а не пробовал искать на оф сайте?

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php

```
<?php
$tests = array(
    "42",
    1337,
    0x539,
    02471,
    0b10100111001,
    1337e0,
    "not numeric",
    array(),
    9.1
);

foreach ($tests as $element) {
    if (is_numeric($element)) {
        echo "'{$element}' - число", PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "'{$element}' - НЕ число", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Результат выполнения данного примера:

```
'42' - число
'1337' - число
'1337' - число
'1337' - число
'1337' - число
'1337' - число
'not numeric' - НЕ число
'Array' - НЕ число
'9.1' - число
```